# If we extend the httpclient somehow to capture some statistics, media player will use our extended Httpclient or not?

Tags: android, httpclient, android-mediaplayer, media

I'm trying to capture some statistics like number of 302's and 200 Oks or the time it takes for the client to receive the content from the streamer (time it takes from the actual request (URL) to the HTTP client until HTTP client sends the content back to the media player).

The cleanest way to do this is to extend HttpClient code. The challenge for me is to know that if the media player (any kind) will use my extended version of HttpClient or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The challenge for me is to know that if the media player (any kind) will use my extended version of HttpClient or not.

It will not. For starters, I don't even know if it uses `HttpClient`. Even if it does, your own `HttpClient` subclasses will not be known to `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Tnx, I'm not sure either! Any suggestions on where to find if Media player (MP) uses HttpClient? I assume MP will eventually creates sort of http connection to pass the URL to and be able to get the content through that